# Creating mesh that divides world by same area?

Tags: qgis, postgis, vector-grid

How can I create a mesh that divides the world by the same area?

If possible, I would like to create it using qgis and postgres
I'm planning to use quadkey or geohash but If you already have standard
I want to use it

Comment: I think it is worth to have a look to this question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265010/creating-geodesic-hexagonal-global-grid-in-qgis/265318#265318

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward method would be to create a mesh in an equal area projection, so that if you create a regular grid with squares or rectangles of the same area, then they will represent the same area in the "real world". For instance, you could pick cylindrical equal area (which has a rectangular shape, so a square grid will fit nicely). Then you simply need to create a fishnet, (see this [question for QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123444/creating-fishnet-grid-shapefile-in-qgis) or this [question for PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16374/creating-regular-polygon-grid-in-postgis)  and reproject it afterward if needed)