# QGIS Hex grid with the shape of vector

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector

I'm trying to make a hex grid net with the shape of polygon. Unfortunately, the grid net is in the rectangle shape (see the screenshot).

Any advice how to do it?

[image]

Comment: This might point you in the right direction https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/265010/creating-geodesic-hexagonal-global-grid-in-qgis I've seen hexagonal grids come up a few times on GIS.SE, a quick search should give you some ideas.

Comment: Did you mean that you try to create a grid inside the green polygon but it came as a rectangle surrounding the polygon ? could you edit your question to provide more info on how you create the grid ?

Comment: J.R Exactly, that was the problem... but when I used the "select by location" and then save selected as a new layer, then it worked and I got the grid with the same shape as "green" polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to @csk's answer is to use **Vector > Research Tools > Select by Location** to select the hexagons which intersect the desired polygon, and them save them to a new layer. This will mean that entire hexagons will be retained, even if they only partially intersect the source polygon.

Comment: Excellent alternate solution. FYI, `Extract by location` (found in the Processing Toolbox) will do the same thing in one step.

Answer (score 1):

Find the `Clip` tool in the Vector menu > Geoprocessing Tools. Use it to clip the grid to the polygon.

[image]